# Output Lines are missing

Tags: perl

I have written small program for getting output from router. but the starting content of the output is missing in output file.

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl -w  
open ( OUTPUT,"> D:\\Routerbkp\\router\\abc.txt" );    
use Control::CLI;                                            
# Create the object instance for SSH                 
$cli = new Control::CLI('SSH');                      
# Connect to host - Note that with SSH,              
#  authentication is part of the connection process  
$cli->connect(  Host            => '10.0.0.1',       
                Username        => 'abc',        
                Password        => 'abc',        
                PrivateKey      => 'C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\key_10.0.0.1_22.pub',    

             );                                      
# Send a command and read the resulting output  
$output1  = $cli->cmd("terminal length 0");
sleep(1);         
$output2  = $cli->cmd("show running-config");
sleep(5);                       
$output8  = $cli->cmd("show alarm current");
sleep(2);

$cli->disconnect;                   
print OUTPUT $output1;
print OUTPUT $output2;
print OUTPUT $output8;
```

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."*

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a problem with your code, your first port of call is ALWAYS `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. 
Then - fix that open statement. Try in the style of:

```
open ( my $output_fh, ">", "D:\\Routerbkp\\router\\abc.txt" ) or die $!;
```

You probably also want to trap any errors from `$cli -> connect()` because there's no guarantee that's worked.

```
my $result = $cli -> connect ( ...

if ( not $result ) { print "Connect failed: ", $cli -> errormode(), ":", $cli -> errormsg(), "\n"; };
```